# How to identify start date and end date using MongoDB aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below is array of documents with collection_date. For a given collection date, I wanted to identify start date and end date using MongoDB aggregation pipeline.

```
[
    {
        "collection_date": 2022-12-01,
        "created_timestamp": 1668177586955,
        "created_by": "SYSTEM",
        "updated_timestamp": 1668177586955,
        "updated_by": "SYSTEM"
    }
]
```

Let's say in the above array collection of documents I have a collection date with 2022-12-01. I am expecting to calculate start date i.e. 2022-12-28 and end date 2022-12-04 for the given collection date using MongoDB aggregation pipeline.

Below is my aggregation pipeline script:

```
db.getCollection("price").aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "convertedDate" : {
                    "$toString" : {
                        "$toDate" : "$collection_date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$set" : {
                "convertedDate" : {
                    "$substr" : [
                        "$convertedDate",
                        0.0,
                        10.0
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    ], 
    {
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

My expectation is for a given collection date, I want to identify the start date of that week and end date of that week. In this case, for year 2022, given collection date is 12-01-2022 for which it's start date of the week is 11-28-2022 and end date of the week is 12-04-2022

Expected output:

```
[
        {
          "convertedDate" : "2022-12-01"        
          "startDate" : "2022-11-28",
          "endDate" : "2022-12-04"
        }
]
```

Comment: start date of 2022-12-28 is later than end date of 2022-12-04? currently your question is unclear. We expect the expected output and your current attempt to be shown.

Comment: @ray I have edited my question and added the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

First result from a google search for "mongodb aggregation pipeline date range" is https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-search-date-range-in-aggregate/153870

Answer (score 0):

Use `$isoDateOfWeek` to identify the day of week and use that as offset with `$dateAdd` and `$dateSubtract` to compute the start and end of the week.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "convertedDate": {
        "$toDate": "$collection_date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "t": {
        "$isoDayOfWeek": "$convertedDate"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "convertedDate": 1,
      "startDate": {
        "$dateSubtract": {
          "startDate": "$convertedDate",
          "unit": "day",
          "amount": "$t"
        }
      },
      "endDate": {
        "$dateAdd": {
          "startDate": "$convertedDate",
          "unit": "day",
          "amount": {
            $subtract: [
              6,
              "$t"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fr3J3z-caNW)